# How to pass variable between observers magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to pass variable (estimated shipping address) from observer of event checkout_submit_before to observer that belong to event payment_method_is_active  so how to proceed please

Comment: create cart attribute or use session variable

Comment: ok i will use session thanks